# Is it possible to define Lists more like Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list

I was wondering if you can define Lists in a similar format to:

```
List<int> blah = [5,7,8];
```

I already tried this and it didn't work, but is there a similar way of doing this? The reason I want to do this is because I am making a method with a List< List< string>> as an argument, and I wanted to be able to do this:

```
DoSomething( [ [1,2,3] , [1,2,3] , [1,2,3] ] );
```

Instead of doing:

```
List<List<string>> foo = new List<List<string>>();
//add each of the "[1,2,3]"s here
DoSomething(foo);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
List<int> blah = new List<int> { 5,7,8 };

DoSomething(new List<List<int>> { new List<int> { 1,2,3 },
                                  new List<int> { 1,2,3 },
                                  new List<int> { 1,2,3 } } );
```

It is called a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Comment: In the second example the type of the outer list should be `List<List<int>>`.